# Augmented Reality QualComms Vuforia

Tags: java, android, eclipse, augmented-reality

I am planing to write an augmented reality application for android devices. "Vuforia" from QualComm seems to be a good start, but I have some questions their website could not answer. As Android 2.1 and up are supported that would mean a lot of devices could possibly use that SDK.

But - This code only runs on ARMv6 or above. Is there any information about how many devices (in percentage) have which QualComm-Processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the precise percentage but ARMv6 and ARMv7 includes the most popular phones out there. [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1596800) is a list of ARMv5,6,7 devices which includes most well-known brands.